# How to catch the letter Q

Tags: c#, string, exception

I am a newbie. I am trying to get a number from the user keyboard. When a number is typed - it counts well, when a letter is typed - an unhandled exception occurs. So I added try / catch and it's ok. I would like to somehow distinguish the letter Q entered from the keyboard and after pressing it end the loop. Please help. I designed something wrong :) thanks

```
using System;
namespace Matematyka_Dyskretna
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Dec_to_bin(int number)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int[] tab = new int[31];
            while (number != 0)
            {
                tab[i++] = number % 2;
                number /= 2;
            }
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                Console.Write(tab[j] + " ");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program konwertuje liczbę w systemie dziesiętnym do systemu dwójkowego\nAby opuścić program wciśnij klawisz Q");
            string ans = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            while (ans != "q")
            {
                int number;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Podaj liczbę w systemie dziesiętnym");
                try
                {
                    number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("Liczba {0} w systemie dwójkowym to: ", number);
                        Dec_to_bin(number);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Złe dane - podaj liczbę calkowitą");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you have looks like it should work. Have you debugged it to see why it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your logic far simpler by using an infinite `while` loop, coupled with `break` and `continue` statements. `int.TryParse` will also allow you to avoid catching an exception.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Program konwertuje liczbę w systemie dziesiętnym do systemu dwójkowego\nAby opuścić program wciśnij klawisz Q");

while (true)
{
    var ans = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (ans == "q")
    {
        break;
    }

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Podaj liczbę w systemie dziesiętnym");

    if (!int.TryParse(ans, out var number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Złe dane - podaj liczbę calkowitą");

        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Liczba {0} w systemie dwójkowym to: ", number);
    Dec_to_bin(number);
}
```

Comment: It looks like what I want, but I couldn't figure it out myself. I'm going to check it out because it looks simple and elegant

Comment: It doesn't work exacly like excepted, but I feel It's a good way. I will modificate

Comment: Glad to be of service. Best of luck in your future coding endeavours!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to build your loop like this using the `readline()` within the while statement.

```
string ans = "";
while ((ans = Console.ReadLine().ToLower()) != "q") {
    Console.WriteLine($"your entered {ans} enter q to quit!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a look like this, and it works fine:

````
            {
                var ans = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (ans == "q")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("koniec!");
                    break;
                }
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Podaj liczbę w systemie dziesiętnym");
                ans = Console.ReadLine();
                if (int.TryParse(ans, out var number))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Liczba {0} w systemie dwójkowym to: ", number);
                    Dec_to_bin(number);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Zła wartość. " + msg);
                }
            }```
````